# I am unable to keep the size of array fixed

Tags: c#

I am having trouble keeping the size of an array fixed. I have to read data from a file. when the number of bytes read is less then 160 the array `MyPCMBuf` changes to the size of bytes read.

```
byte[] MyPCMBuf;
MyPCMBuf = new byte[160];

BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileNamein, FileMode.Open)) ;

Array.Clear (MyPCMBuf,0,160);

MyPCMBuf = reader.ReadBytes(160); //if bytes read =20 , size of MyPCMBuf becomes 20
```

What is going on and how to avoid it?

Comment: when you do MyPCMBuf = reader.ReadBytes(160); you are assigning reader.ReadBytes(160)'s return result to MyPCMBuf, which if there are only 20 bytes left the return array would have length 20

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)? It explicitly states that the return value is "A byte array containing data read from the underlying stream. **This might be less than the number of bytes requested if the end of the stream is reached**."

Answer (score 4):

That's because [ReadBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a new byte array.

If you want to read bytes into an existing array, call [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143295(v=vs.110).aspx).

That is:

```
int bytesRead = reader.Read(myBuffer, 0, 160);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have no problem keeing the size fixed.

`ReadBytes` returns a new array. That simple. The old one never changes size.

If you want to use your buffer, user another method, for example:

```
public virtual int Read(
    byte[] buffer,
    int index,
    int count
)
```

on that class. Then you keep your array.

Comment: Whats up with your casing ?

Comment: @user2711965 Probably related to the [FGinW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) problem. Typing as fast as you can without looking back and of course no time wasted with code formatting to be the first.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, yeah looks like that is the case

Comment: Add to that: Being the only one to actually look into the documentation to find the right method. Takes time, too.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `BinaryReader` at all. Use the `FileStream` returned by `Open` and call its `Read` method. If you don't assign to `MyPCMBuf` its length cannot possibly change.

Unrelated: Use `Array.Clear (MyPCMBuf,0,MyPCMBuf.Length);`. Less redundancy. Less potential for errors. Use `using`. Don't initialize `MyPCMBuf` if you always overwrite it. Don't clear it redundantly. I see a lot of misunderstandings here. Be more rigorous in your approach to programming. It appears you don't really understand all the language features and APIs you are using. That's dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `MyPCMBuf` in line

```
MyPCMBuf = reader.ReadBytes(160);
```

Thus, line `MyPCMBuf = new byte[160];` is irrelevant in your code.
You are not really doing what you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

`reader.ReadBytes(160)` will create a new byte array of size at most 160. It's not storing values in the array you already had. That one is send to Garbage Collection.